# LINQ to entities does not recognise the method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iqueryable

I understand why I'm getting the following error, however I'm not sure how I could go about providing a solution that can get around it.

```
{System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsStatus(CDAX.DataModel.ProcessStatusEnum)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I don't want to just return IEnumerable as I want to translate the filters to an underlying SQL statement so that I don't query on so many rows etc

```
    public override IQueryable<Session> GetQuery()
    {
        Func<Session, bool> activeSessions = (session) => !session.IsStatus(ProcessStatusEnum.Deleted);

        // these functions are causing issues.  I'm not sure how to change them to
        // work with IQueryable??   
        return base.GetQuery().Where(p => activeSessions(p) && _queryFilter.FilterOn(p.Customer));
    }
```

The _queryFilter class is an interface such as:

```
public interface IDataQueryFilter
{
    bool FilterOn(Customer obj);
}
```

Customer is just an Entity object in my database with properties such as Id, CustomerNumber etc

Session is another Entity object in my database and the IsStatus method is such:

```
    public bool IsStatus(ProcessStatusEnum status)
    {
        return SessionStatus == (byte)status;
    }
```

The conditions I use are typically very simple so I believe they should be able to translate to SQL.  I guess it's just because they are within functions that they cannot.  Could I perhaps use something else as the return type to get these to work?

Comment: Try adding `.ToList ()` after `base.GetQuery ()`.

Comment: @Shredderroy I'm sort of wanting to apply the filter at the sql level to avoid unnecessary objects being brought back from the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ to Entities is trying to convert your LINQ query into SQL statements. It doesn't now how to perform your custom Func on the database directly so it throws this error.

You could simply change your `IsStatus` method into `session.Status == ProcessStatusEnum.Deleted` but you will likely then get an error about the second function.

The simplest way to 'fix' this is to put a `.ToList()` between the part to perform on the database, and the part you want to do in memory. Obviously the more that goes on the database the better however.

For your filter, you might look at changing your FilterOn into a method that returns an Expression tree:

```
public interface IDataQueryFilter
{
    Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> FilterOn();
}
```

And then for example if you want all customers in London pass in an instance of LondonCustomFilter:

```
public class LondonCustomFilter : IDataQueryFilter {
    Expression<Func<Customer, Bool>> FilterOn() {
        return (customer) => customer.City == "London";
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated the answer with some ideas on your second function and how to change it.

Comment: Awesome.  Almost, but the GetQuery method is working on Entity Session (which happens to have a Customer) on it.  So my interface would need to expose Express<Func<Customer, bool>>.  Ideally I want to do the way you suggested but not sure how?

Comment: Well the easiest way would be to change it to Expression<Func<Session, bool>> and take the hit. The hard way is probably to build up an expression tree builder method that takes one expression and returns another. Try looking into the PredicateBuilder class (google it).

Answer (score 0):

Your `IsStatus` method call cannot be converted into SQL. I suggest you to do status verification manually without method call.

```
(session) => session.Status != ProcessStatusEnum.Deleted
```

Another option is bringing all entities into memory (by executing `ToList()`), but that will be slow.

Comment: cheers, I'm trying to get away with bring it into memory.  I was hoping I could use some fancy Expression syntax or something (I have not idea) to get around this