# EF Poco method unknown in LINQ

Tags: entity-framework, linq

To get a list of all unbalanced orders I have the following (simpliefied) Linq

```
var UnbalancedOrders = db.Orders.Where(x => x.TenantId == Transaction.TenantId && x.State == OrderStates.Placed && x.Balance() > 0);
```

Balance() is a method on the Order model calculating how much of the due amount is not paid yet.

When I run the code I get :

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double Balance()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I understand that this does not work this way, but is there a workaround to actually use that method in an Linq statement ?

UPDATE

```
    public class Order : BasketBase, IModel, IMultiTenant
    {
        ...
        public double TotalPayments()
        {
            return Payments.Sum(x => x.Amount);
        }

        public double Balance()
        {
            return (TotalAmmount() - TotalPayments());
        }
}
```

FROM this [SO-ISSUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012495/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognise-the-method) I took the idea to first turn it into a list only using the part that can be translated to SQL and then apply the part that is not translatble to SQL.

```
var UnbalancedOrders = db.Orders.Where(x => x.TenantId == Transaction.TenantId && x.State == OrderStates.Placed).ToList().Where(x => x.Balance() > 0);
```

This seems to be working but does not look to be the best-practice : getting all the data from DB and filter a second time ?

Comment: does your `Orders` contain a method  `Balance()` ? please show your POCO

Comment: Yes order has a method Balance(). The comiler does not complain about the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just the reserved word `let` in LINQ syntax, like this:

```
from order in db.Orders
let totalPayments = order.Payments.Sum(x => x.Amount)
let totalAmmount = order.Payments.Sum(x => x.Amount) //duplicated totalPayment because IDK this formula
let balance = totalAmmount() - totalPayments
where order.TenantId == Transaction.TenantId && x.State == OrderStates.Placed && balance > 0
select order
```

If you don't want to duplicate the Balance formula, you can use a combination of using DTO and AutoMapper, like this:

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(configuration => configuration.AddProfile<OrderProfile>());

        using (var ctx = new Ctx())
        {
            ctx.Database.CreateIfNotExists();

            ctx.Orders.Add(new Order { Value = 100, OtherAdditionalValue = 1 });
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            ctx.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;
            // this way works, but fetch all database first 
            var orders = ctx.Orders.ToList().Where(x => x.Balance > 100);

            //this way works, but fetch only charges that has balance > 100
            var chargingsDtos = ctx.Orders.ProjectTo<OrderDTO>().Where(x => x.Balance > 100).ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class Ctx : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    private static readonly Func<Order, decimal> CompiledBalance = BalanceExpression.Compile();
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public decimal OtherAdditionalValue { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance => CompiledBalance(this);

    public static Expression<Func<Order, decimal>> BalanceExpression
        => c => c.Value + c.OtherAdditionalValue;
}

public class OrderProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderDTO>()
              .ForMember(c => c.Balance, de => de.MapFrom(Order.BalanceExpression));
    }
}

public class OrderDTO
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
}
```

And the SQL query output is this:

```
Opened connection at 09/12/2015 16:44:36 -03:00

SELECT
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Extent1].[Value] AS [Value],
    [Extent1].[OtherAdditionalValue] AS [OtherAdditionalValue]
    FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1]


-- Executing at 09/12/2015 16:44:36 -03:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 09/12/2015 16:44:36 -03:00

Opened connection at 09/12/2015 16:44:36 -03:00

SELECT
    1 AS [C1],
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Extent1].[Value] + [Extent1].[OtherAdditionalValue] AS [C2]
    FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Value] + [Extent1].[OtherAdditionalValue]) > cast(100 as decimal(18))


-- Executing at 09/12/2015 16:44:36 -03:00

-- Completed in 1 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 09/12/2015 16:44:36 -03:00
```

As you can see, the line `var orders = ctx.Orders.ToList().Where(x => x.Balance > 100);` fetch all database, and other line, using Projection from AutoMapper include Where clause in SQL.
Using this you still have the Balance property in your model, but now you have the BalanceExpression that hold the expression to get the Balance value, and if you change it, it will work everywhere.

Comment: Is this also possible in the cascaded syntax ? Problem with this solution is that whenever the totalamount formula changes it has to be changed here to.

Comment: @BrilBroeder You can do this in lambda way too. About the formula change, that's a problem, but I prefer do it and get better perf than use ToList, also we must check how often the formula will change, I have been working in big application, and I have something like that, that never changed.

Comment: I agree on the likelyhood of the change, but if it does, it might be hell to find that bug :-) I'm going for the tolist aproach although it is lower in performance but that is not a big issue in this case because it is in a batch job anyway. Thx for the input it is now clear what option I have.

Comment: @BrilBroeder There is a way that you can have Balance method, but it will use Expression, and AutoMapper, but its a bit more complex code. So if you need it let me know.

Comment: @BrilBroeder I added a new other solution that you will have no problem if you change the Balance.

Comment: Looks great. Never used automapper before. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution I went for :

```
var UnbalancedOrders = db.Orders.Where(x => x.TenantId == Transaction.TenantId && x.State == OrderStates.Placed).ToList().Where(x => x.Balance() > 0);
```

Just for reference some background info :

```
db.Orders.Where(x => x.TenantId == Transaction.TenantId && x.State == OrderStates.Placed).ToList()
```

Is Linq to EF and will be translated to SQL.

```
.Where(x => x.Balance() > 0)
```

Is Linq to entities hence methods of the POCO can be used.

CONTRA :

The ToList() is downloading the entire set to memory and then a second filtering on the list is done. Hence a lot of MEM and CPU usage.

PRO :
This solution is independant from anychanges in the Balance() method/formula. Hence will not introduce a bug if Balance() changes.

Answer (score -1):

First create a VM and save the worked out Balance() in it so that all the calculations are done. LINQ does not work on computed values. Then use your LINQ statement

```
//The proposed VM. add fields as required

public class OrderVM 
{
   public int OrderID {get;set;}  //Guessing this field as you hv not shown it
   public double TotalPayments{get;set;}

    public double Balance{get;set;}
}

// **** Add this below in another class 
 :
 :
 :
//Note the calculated field is not a part of the LINQ I have removed it.
var allOrders = db.orders.ToList(var UnbalancedOrders = db.Orders.Where(x => x.TenantId == Transaction.TenantId && x.State == OrderStates.Placed ) //filter
List<OrderVM> listOrderVM= new List<OrderVM>();

foreach (var item in allOrders)
{
    OrderVM o = new OrderVM;
    o.OrderID = Item.OrderID
    // add more fields if u need them for the op.
    o.Balance = Item.Balance();
    o.TotalPayments = Item.TotalPayments();

    //You could do an IF here and add only those that are greater than zero...
    //But I am showing you how to use LINQ when you have a calculation.

    listOrderVM.Add(o);
 }

 var selectedOrders = listOrderVM.ToList(x=>x.Balance>0);

//selectedOrders will have all orders with balance > 0
//Now LINQ will work.
```

Comment: can you give an example because there are almost as many interpretations of what a VM is or how it should work as there are dev's :-)

Comment: What kind of code is this? It doesn't even compile.

Comment: Well the VM is the model... then the code is used in another class.

Comment: Ah come on, look at f.i. `db.orders.ToList(var UnbalancedOrders`.

Comment: Actually, I got that part from BrilBroeder. I presumed it to work. I am just showing here how to use a VM to make LINQ work.

Comment: Please do not take my code snippit and use it in 'your way of working' and then blame me for it as being bad code.